# Why multiprocessing is slower than one process execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

i have the next code in python 3.6.5

```
def normalize_item(self, item):
    morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
    return {'phrase': item['phrase'],
            'words': [morph.parse(word.lower())[0].normal_form
                      if word.lower() not in self.normed
                      else self.normed[word.lower()]
                      for word in item['phrase'].split(' ')],
            'active': item['active'],
            'cash': item['cash']}

def __normalize_phrase_to_dict(self, phrases):
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=int(mp.cpu_count()))
    result = pool.map(self.normalize_item, phrases)
    pool.close()
    self.phrases = result
```

It working in 8 time slower, than simple iterative execution.
Please, explain me why this happening and how i can fix it. I should increase performance, but now i just make it slower. I have laptop with intel core i7 8550u, the count of data to process is something about 80-90 thousands. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: show how you're calling the function in both cases

Comment: Where does `phrases` comes from?

Comment: def __read_files(self, path_a, path_b, path_phrases, path_normed):
        phrases_in = pd.read_csv(path_phrases, usecols=[0, 1, 2], header=0, names=['phrase', 'active', 'cash']) \
            .to_dict('records')

        self.__normalize_phrase_to_dict(phrases_in)

This function is called in init method of class.